# Find all the $z \in \Bbb{C}$ such that the following series converges:

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

> Find all the $z \in \Bbb{C}$ such that the following series converges:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z+i)^{3n}}{(n^3 + 1)^{1/3}e^{3n}}$$

To solve this problem I proceed as usually, first of all, setting $w=z+i$ and considering:

$$\limsup \bigg(\frac{|w|^{3n}}{(n^3 + 1)^{1/3}e^{3n}} \bigg)^{1/n}=\frac{|w|^3}{e^3}$$

And therefore the series converges if $\frac{|w|^3}{e^3} <1$. Now for the case in which $\frac{|w|^3}{e^3}=1$ that is, when $|w|=e$, I usually use Dirichlet's Criteria to show that if $w \neq e$ then the series converges in the border.

Therefore, taking $\xi \in \Bbb{C}$ with $|\xi|=1$, such that $w=e\xi$ I rewrite the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{3n}\xi^{3n}}{(n^3 + 1)^{1/3}e^{3n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\xi^{3n}}{(n^3 + 1)^{1/3}}$$

So here is where I would use Dirichlet by bounding the partial sums of $\sum\xi^n$ with the usual trick ($|\sum^{k} \xi^n|=|\frac{\xi^{k+1}-1}{\xi -1}|\leq \frac{2}{\xi-1}$).

The problem is that I have in the summand, $\xi^{3n}$. Is there any way I can transform this into the usual problem or I should use another criteria?

Comment: Let $\zeta = \xi^3$. There are in this case three points on the boundary of the disk of convergence where the series diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. You may just write
$$
\sum_{n=0}^k \xi^{3n}=\sum_{n=0}^k \left(\xi^3\right)^n=\frac{\xi^{3(k+1)}-1}{\xi^3-1}.
$$